# Text issues when exporting from ArcMap 10.1 to Illustrator CS5

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, export, text, illustrator

When exporting from ArcMap 10.1 to Illustrator CS5 I am getting a lot of errors (red box with plus sign). I have used this workflow in ArcMap 9.3 with less problems (there may have been a couple of errors but not the hundreds I am getting with version 10.1). I have played with the export dpi but the result doesn't change.

Can anyone advise with any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: The TextTweaker Script should fix this issue in Illustrator http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/textTweaker.js

Answer (score 1):

Red box with a plus means your text is bigger than your clipping mask or text box.  You might try deleting all the clipping masks in your Illustrator file's label (text) layer and see if that helps?